# Remote Desktop Connection Client vs. Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

What is the difference between [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18140) and [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12)?  Has the later replaced the former?  Do they have the same functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Remote Desktop Connection Client vs. Remote Desktop

They appear to have the same functionality.

However they are for **different** versions of OSX. See below.

---

#### Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac Version 2.1.1

> Published 5/5/2011.
>
> Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac 2.1.1 lets you connect from your Macintosh computer to a Windows-based computer and then work with applications and files on the Windows-based computer.

...

> Operating System Versions: Mac OS X version 10.5.8 or a later version
> of  Mac OS.
>
> Note:  **Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac (version
> 2.1.1) is not supported for use with Mac OS X v10.7 (Lion) or later**.

Source [Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Client for Mac Version 2.1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18140)

---

#### Microsoft Remote Desktop

> Version 8.0.15
> Updated: Mar 20, 2015.
>
> With the Microsoft Remote Desktop app, you can connect to a remote PC and your work resources from almost anywhere. Experience the power of Windows with RemoteFX in a Remote Desktop client designed to help you get your work done wherever you are.

...

> Compatibility: **OS X 10.7 or later, 64-bit processor**

Source [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417?mt=12)